# Cannot configure Indexed TypeRepresentationStrategy for spring-data-neo4j 3.0.2

Tags: java, xml, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to configure `spring-data-neo4j 3.0.1.RELEASE` to work with a legacy (2.3.5.RELEASE) database. Therefore, I followed the documentation in order to configure the **INDEXED** `TypeRepresentationStrategy`. However, it does not seem to have any effect as I still see the same type of Cypher queries in the log:

```
Executing cypher query: START `abc`=node:__types__(className="abc") RETURN `abc`
```

I would have expected to instead query for `node.__type__ = "x.y.z.abc"`. Here is the xml config:

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="typeRepresentationStrategyFactory" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabase"/>
    <constructor-arg value="Indexed"/>
</bean>

<neo4j:config  storeDirectory="${app.neo4j.location}" base-package="x.y.z.*" />
<neo4j:repositories base-package="x.y.z.*" />
```

Seems like the type representation strategy configuration is ignored.

Comment: Try placing it below the `<neo:config />` element. Ordering matters as i suspect that now your bean is overwritten by the one from the `<neo4j:config />`.

Comment: That did not help. Still getting the same results/log.

Comment: That query above is correct, so it uses the correct strategy, it uses the index to find nodes of that type, but it uses the property when you load a single node to know which type it is.

Comment: No, it is not. spring-data-neo4j-2.x uses the FQNs as type values, which I have also seen directly in the graph using the neo4j web administration app. Also the first query above queries for the type as a label property...